# Error in launching Jupyter notebook on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Followed this blog post on creating a new VM and trying to launch Jupyter notebook on GCP. 
https://medium.com/@kn.maragatham09/installing-jupyter-notebook-on-google-cloud-11979e40cd10
Getting this error message
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with the obvious ones?

1. Does the Cert exist? (maybe it was removed along the process..)
2. Does the Cert has correct ownership?
3. Does jupyter/user executing jupyter has the right to access the Cert?

Maybe you could try and run Jupyter in verbose mode. And post it here.

Comment: I was able to point to the cert location by using                                                    
jupyter notebook --certfile=~/certs/mycert.pem                                                                   However, the notebook still does not launch. I am getting 'This site can’t be reached'error message.

Comment: Did you open the ports necessary for jupyter frontend?

Comment: Yes, I did. I followed the instructions in the blog exactly

Comment: It turned out to be a permissions issue. Also, I had to specify the location of my cert when I ran jupyter notebook:
jupyter notebook — certfile=~/certs/mycert.pem. @Andrey Bulezyuk - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fyi, GCP now offers a easy to use, pre-setup Jupyter Notebook environment called [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/).  Have you tried using that instead?  You won't need to worry about setting up any certs :)